# react slider prevent image reload on change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, browser

I'm making an image slider with React and running into an issue where the images are being re-requested from the remote URL

Here's a JS Fiddle that illustrates the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/iioinc/sz8pf245/

When I first open the image slider and go to the next slide, the first and second images are loaded. Then when I go to the previous slide, the first image loads again. This continues on each slide change - the images get requested again from the same remote URLs:

[image: same images requested multiple times]

Here's the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const slideImages = [
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/189349/pexels-photo-189349.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/585759/pexels-photo-585759.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
];

const Slider = (props) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(1);

  const onNavNext = () => {
    const nextIndex =
      currentIndex === slideImages.length - 1 ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;

    setCurrentIndex(nextIndex);
  };

  const onNavPrev = () => {
    const nextIndex =
      currentIndex === 0 ? slideImages.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;

    setCurrentIndex(nextIndex);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p onClick={onNavPrev}>Prev</p>
      <div className="slider-container">
        <img className="slide" src={slideImages[currentIndex]} />
      </div>
      <p onClick={onNavNext}>Next</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Slider />, rootElement);
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iioinc/sz8pf245/

I saw a related question here: [Prevent image from rerendering at every state change - React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653170/prevent-image-from-rerendering-at-every-state-change-react)

But it didn't work because I think its a different scenario - the HTML is being replaced so memoize isn't helping

How do I prevent the images from reloading on each slide change? Fetching the same data is a waste and with large images the user can see the image reloading each time

Comment: I had the same issue with routing from react-router. Apparently the accepted asnwer fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images is reloaded because you turn on "Disable cache" option in Devtools - Network. Turn off this option will solve your problem.